# Scrolling a fixed div

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-position

The following works as intended, except one thing... I can't scroll the menu when it's down! For the life of me I can't figure out how to solve it  :(

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fixed position, but if I change that then the menu won't work as intended (being stuck on top (all the time)).

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVk82/3/)

This is the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var topMenu = $('#topMenu');
var topMenuItem = $('#topMenu ul li a');
var top = $('#top');
var menuTrigger = $('.menu-trigger');
var time = 350;
var easing = 'easeOutCirc';

topMenu.css({
    'top': -(topMenu.height())
});

menuTrigger.on('click', function () {
    if (top.hasClass('closed')) {
        top.animate({
            top: topMenu.height()
        },
        time,
        easing);
        top.removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
    } else if(top.hasClass('open')) {
        top.animate({
            top: 0
        },
        time,
        easing);
        top.removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
    }; 
});

topMenuItem.on('click', function () {

    if (topMenu.offset().top == 0) {

        top.animate({
            top: 0
        },
        time,
        easing);
    };
});});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll the menu when it's down"?

Comment: Do you want to scroll the content when you click on the menu and revert back when close the menu?

Comment: If you try the fiddle you will notice that the content of the menu can't be scrolled. So your stuck with whatever you see... Also, you can't close the menu again since you can't scroll to the menu trigger. Try removing the li elements to 1 or two, you'll see what I mean

Comment: @DeepakBiswal If I understand you correctly then yes, I'm trying to make the menu scrollable when open (but only the menu) and then when it's closed, back the fixed position on top